# TypeError - What does this error mean?

Tags: python, file, typeerror

So, i've been writing this program that takes a HTMl file, replaces some text and puts the return back into a different file in a different directory.

This error happened.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Users/Glenn/jack/HTML_Task/src/HTML Rewriter.py", line 19, in <module>
        with open (os.path.join("/Users/Glenn/jack/HTML_Task/src", out_file)):
              File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/posixpath.py", line 89, in join
        genericpath._check_arg_types('join', a, *p)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/genericpath.py", line 143, in _check_arg_types
        (funcname, s.__class__.__name__)) from None
    TypeError: join() argument must be str or bytes, not 'TextIOWrapper'
```

Below is my code. Has anyone got any solutions I could implement, or should I kill it with fire.

```
    import re
    import os
    os.mkdir ("dest")

    file = open("2016-06-06_UK_BackToSchool.html").read()
    text_filtered = re.sub(r'http://', '/', file)
    print (text_filtered)

    with open ("2016-06-06_UK_BackToSchool.html", "wt") as out_file:
        print ("testtesttest")

    with open (os.path.join("/Users/Glenn/jack/HTML_Task/src", out_file)):
               out_file.write(text_filtered)

    os.rename("/Users/Glenn/jack/HTML_Task/src/2016-06-06_UK_BackToSchool.html", "/Users/Glenn/jack/HTML_Task/src/dest/2016-06-06_UK_BackToSchool.html")
```

Comment: Check your indentation; out_file does not exist at your second `with` statement, and also that `with` does not have an `as` clause on it. Otherwise, I believe your issue involves trying to join `out_file` and a string- `out_file` is not a string, and won't be `join`-able. You would need to join the name.

Answer (score 2):

```
with open (os.path.join("/Users/Glenn/jack/HTML_Task/src", out_file)):
```

Here `out_file` if `TextIOWrapper`, not string.

`os.path.join` takes string as arguments.

---

1. Do not use keywords name as variable.  `file` is keyword.
2. Do not use space in between function call  `os.mkdir ("dest")`

Comment: just to be pedantic : s/file pointer/TextIOWrapper instance/  ;)

Comment: I am not getting @brunodesthuilliers. Can u explain again? :)

Comment: You wrote "Here `out_file` is a file pointer" - technically, it's _not_ a "file pointer" since Python has no pointers, it's a `TextIOWrapper` instance ;)

Answer (score 1):

try to change this:

```
with open ("2016-06-06_UK_BackToSchool.html", "wt") as out_file
```

on this:

```
with open ("2016-06-06_UK_BackToSchool.html", "w") as out_file:
```

or this:

```
with open ("2016-06-06_UK_BackToSchool.html", "wb") as out_file:
```